# Lodash: slice array and keep a specific item

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects that I get from an API and 1 of the objects has a "selected" property. I need to slice that array to only have 3 objects and 1 of the objects needs to be the "selected" object. I'm using lodash in an angular application but I'm not limited on how to achieve this, although I would prefer an answer that uses lodash. Thanks in advance... See example below:

```js
//Sample array
var fruits = [{
  id: 1,
  fruit: "apple",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  fruit: "pear",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 3,
  fruit: "orange",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 4,
  fruit: "pineaple",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 5,
  fruit: "mango",
  selected: true
}, {
  id: 6,
  fruit: "peach",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 7,
  fruit: "strawberry",
  selected: false
}];
```

Expected result:

```js
var fruits = [{
  id: 1,
  fruit: "apple",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 2,
  fruit: "pear",
  selected: false
}, {
  id: 5,
  fruit: "mango",
  selected: true
}];
```

Comment: it is unclear the criteria needed to select the other 2 items.  Should it be random, start with the true one and get the rest.  Is it always 3?

Comment: Yes, the other ones can be picked at random, there is also an ID property that we can sort them by if we want to. I have updated the example.

Answer (score 1):

Making like 3 assumptions here, but:

```
var sliced = fruits.slice(0,3);

for (var i=3; i<fruits.length; i+=1)
    if (fruits[i].selected)
        sliced[0] = fruits[i];
```

Comment: I like this one, short and simple; one "problem" could be that if the seleted item happens to be second or third in the array, then it is not become the first one it he array we end up with.

Answer (score 0):

Never understood the appeal of underscore or lodash post IE8. Tons of excellent convenience methods are available in modern JS. More on native JS array methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

```
    //Sample array
    var fruits = [{
      fruit: "apple",
      selected: false
    }, {
      fruit: "pear",
      selected: false
    }, {
      fruit: "orange",
      selected: false
    }, {
      fruit: "pineaple",
      selected: false
    }, {
      fruit: "mango",
      selected: true
    }, {
      fruit: "peach",
      selected: false
    }, {
      fruit: "strawberry",
      selected: false
    }];

function fruitCheck(obj){
    var isDesiredFruit = (obj.fruit === 'mango') ||
        (obj.fruit === 'peach') ||
        (obj.fruit === 'strawberry');
    return isDesiredFruit;
}

var filteredFruits = fruits.filter(fruitCheck);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
function getThreeFruits (fruits) {
  var split = _.partition(fruits, { selected: true })
  var selectedFruit = split[0]
  var twoOtherFruits = split[1].slice(0, 2)
  return selectedFruit.concat(twoOtherFruits)
}
```

Comment: this was great, it worked as expected however I decided to use .reduce instead... Ended up with this `return user.userStoreAccesses
        .reduce(function(arr, el) {
          if (el.defaultStore) {
            return [el].concat(arr).slice(0, 3);
          }
          if (arr.length > 2) {
            return arr;
          }
          arr.push(el);
          return arr;
        }, []);`

Comment: After I wrote the comment I went back and decided to try a different way...  Here is my final iteration `return _(user.userStoreAccesses)
        .chain()
        .sortBy("defaultStore")
        .reverse()
        .slice(0, 3)
        .value()`

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to go about this! This is another Vanilla Javascript one, fill free to mix and match according to your actual specs.

```
var fruits = [{
  fruit: "apple",
  selected: false
}, {
  fruit: "pear",
  selected: false
}, {
  fruit: "orange",
  selected: false
}, {
  fruit: "pineaple",
  selected: false
}, {
  fruit: "mango",
  selected: true
}, {
  fruit: "peach",
  selected: false
}, {
  fruit: "strawberry",
  selected: false
}];

var selectedFruits = fruits.reduce((result, el) => {
  if(el.selected) {
    return Array(el).concat(result).slice(0, 3);
  }
  if (result.length > 2) return result;
  result.push(el);
  return result;
}, Array());

console.log(selectedFruits);
```

Comment: This is great! I modified it a little and ended up with `return user.userStoreAccesses
        .reduce(function(arr, el) {
          if (el.defaultStore) {
            return [el].concat(arr).slice(0, 3);
          }
          if (arr.length > 2) {
            return arr;
          }
          arr.push(el);
          return arr;
        }, []);`
Thank you for the response :)

Comment: After I wrote the comment I went back and decided to try a different way... Here is my final iteration return _(user.userStoreAccesses) .chain() .sortBy("defaultStore") .reverse() .slice(0, 3) .value()

Answer (score 0):

```
var z= _.sortBy(fruits,function(obj){return obj.selected})
var result.push(z.slice(0,2));
result.push(z[z.length-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After Reviewing all the answers I decided to use something like this.

```js
return user.userStoreAccesses
  .reduce(function(arr, el) {
    //check if current obj is the defaultStore
    if (el.defaultStore) {
      return [el].concat(arr).slice(0, 3);
    }
    //the moment the array is greater than 2 stop execution
    if (arr.length > 2) {
      return arr;
    }
    //keep pushing items to the array until...
    arr.push(el);
    return arr;
  }, []);
```

However I decided to go a little simpler than that by chaining a few lodash methods (which was my original intention). Here is the final result:

```js
return _(user.userStoreAccesses)
  .chain()
  .sortBy("defaultStore")
  .reverse()
  .slice(0, 3)
  .value();
```

Thanks for the answers, they were very helpful!!
I hope my method is also useful for somebody else :)